# How to authenticate users using CakePHP 2.2?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.2

I've read the documentation for the [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) core library
, and it's not really clear how to use it. It seems to assume a lot of prior knowledge.

Specifically:

> You configure authentication handlers using $this->Auth->authenticate.
>   You can configure one or many handlers for authentication. Using
>   multiple handlers allows you to support different ways of logging
>   users in. When logging users in, authentication handlers are checked
>   in the order they are declared. Once one handler is able to identify
>   the user, no other handlers will be checked. Conversely you can halt
>   all authentication by throwing an exception. You will need to catch
>   any thrown exceptions, and handle them as needed.
>
> **You can configure authentication handlers in your controller’s
>   beforeFilter or, in the $components array**. You can pass configuration
>   information into each authentication object, using an array:

So in my `PeopleController` I wrote in the example code:

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
        'Form',
        'Basic'
    );

    public function index() {

    }
}
```

And this exception fires:

> syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION) Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
>
> Stack Trace CORE\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php line 162 →
>   ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(integer, string, string, integer)
>   [internal function] → ErrorHandler::handleError(integer, string,
>   string, integer, array) CORE\Cake\Core\App.php line 926 →
>   call_user_func(string, integer, string, string, integer, array)
>   CORE\Cake\Core\App.php line 899 → App::_checkFatalError() [internal
>   function] → App::shutdown()

Can anybody provide a simple example of how to protect a Controller so only an authenticated user can access it? Can I also protect individual Action functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you should do it in the `beforeFilter()`

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
        'Form',
        'Basic'
    );
}
```

And also, as Martin already mentioned, `$this` can be used only in an (object) method, as `$this` refers to the current object from which the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have instance references while in the class definition.

`$this` is only accessible in a class method.

In your controller (let say, AppController.php):

```
    public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => 'login',
        'loginRedirect' => 'home',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array( 'password' => 'password' ),
                'scope' => array( 'User.active' => true )
            )
        )
    )
);
```